# pyqt5 continuous image refresh

Tags: python, pyqt5

this is what I want to do:
Using python, I want to download a picture instantly from the server and display it instantly in the pyqt5 window. I managed to download it instantly, but I do not know how to show it in the window instantly. how can I do it?

My instant download code:

```py
import requests
from os import _exit as osexit
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
def a():
    while True:
        url="http://localhost/bgimage.png"
        r=requests.get(url)
        open(f"asd/image.png","wb").write(r.content)
        sleep(0.5)
def b():
    while True:
        print("q. ÇIKIŞ")
        işlem=input("İşlem: ")
        if işlem.lower()=="q":
            osexit(1)

t1=Thread(target=a)
t2=Thread(target=b)

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

My code to show the picture:

```py
    import sys
    
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets,QtGui
    
    
    
    def Pencere():
    
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
        pencere = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        pencere.setWindowTitle("ANLIK RESİM")
        etiket2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(pencere)
        etiket2.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("resim.png"))
    
        pencere.setGeometry(0,0,500,500)
    
        pencere.show()
    
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    
    
    Pencere()
```

How can I constantly refresh this picture?

(I used google translate)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `QNetworkAccessManager` to fetch url repeatedly, and since it has asyncronous signal-slot api, you dont even need threads, but it's probbly a good idea to add timer to limit number of requests (per second) to server.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtNetwork, QtGui

class Loader(QtCore.QObject):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        manager = QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager()
        manager.finished.connect(self.onFinished)
        self._manager = manager
        
    def start(self, url, label):
        self._url = url
        self._label = label
        self.request()

    def request(self):
        manager = self._manager
        req = QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest(QtCore.QUrl(self._url))
        res = manager.get(req)

    def onFinished(self, reply):
        data = reply.readAll()
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap()
        pixmap.loadFromData(data)
        self._label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(100, self.request)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
    label.show()
    loader = Loader()
    url = "http://localhost/bgimage.png"
    loader.start(url, label)
    app.exec()
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could also add a minimal description that explains what your code does and why you wrote it like that, since it's very different than what the OP provided in their example.